# running macOS UI based Application as root

Tags: terminal, applications, permission, launchd, macos

I'd like to open a specific macOS application which require root privileges (uid=0 or gid=0) in order to access specific files. However, when trying to run with `sudo` directly I get the following error:

```
sudo /Applications/myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/myApp
Illegal instruction: 4
```

and if running it indirectly using `open` it gets the uid of current user and not root.

any ideas who to do it ?

Comment: Do you have access to the application's source code? Is this an application you have created?

Comment: yes, and I give access to encrypted files only if running from root (uid=0)

Comment: Perhaps you can advise using privilege elevation option upon entering root credentials ? I see that the method for this is already deprecated (AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges). So I have to use the SmJobBless, right ?

Comment: If the files are encrypted anyway and a password is required to access them, why go through all the pain of limiting access to a specific user? If the encryption is done right it will not add an additional layer of security; if it's done wrong it gives you a false sense of security.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Security Risk

macOS is not designed to have general applications run as the root user. This would be viewed as a security risk by Apple's engineers.

### XPC Services

Running a graphical application, and all the frameworks that requires, as `root` is not advisable. The surface area for security problems and mistakes is huge.

[`AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1540038-authorizationexecutewithprivileg) is now deprecated. Instead, Apple promote [XPC Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html) as a way dividing up sections of applications that require higher privileges.